# Angular copy object to dialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui

I'm looking for a way to pass an object to a dialog in angular. I want to be able to display text from the table in a modal but this doesn't seem to be working. The modal appears on the click event but it is not getting any text from the object.

Here's the code in this plunk so you can see what I mean:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ETy10U?p=preview

I'd like to say that this is not a bug with angular but I'm not sure.

Comment: `resolve: { item: angular.copy(item) }` solves the issue. But I don;t know why is that. Few hours ago, I used `resolve: { item: function() {return angular.copy(item);} }` & it worked. This is weird.

Comment: Just as some additional information, the first one `resolve: { item: angular.copy(item) }` worked because I was using an older version of ui-bootstrap. `resolve: { item: function() {return angular.copy(item);} }` works on 0.4.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to make the Angular UI [$dialog](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dialog) work like a modal, even though Angular UI already has a [directive for modals](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal).

In this case, you would want to set a flag for showing the modal (the example uses `$scope.shouldBeOpen`) and then set the item you want to disaply on `$scope.item`

```
<div modal="shouldBeOpen" close="close()" options="opts">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3>I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">{{item}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-warning cancel" ng-click="close()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

When the flag is set to `true`, the modal will be displayed.  In order to close it, you would need to have a function which sets the flag to `false`.